# How to add pagination and limit to cosmos db

Tags: pagination, azure-cosmosdb

I want to specify the number of records to return from the database. The only way I've come up with that allows me to do that, is by setting the MaxItemCount = 1, so that each feed response contains only one result, and then readNext from the iterator the wanted number of times. I don't know enough about RUs and what goes on behind the scenes with cosmos db, but I suspect setting MaxItemCount = 1 is bad practice. So is there any other way to do this?

```
public async Task<(IEnumerable<T> Results, string ContinuationToken)> ReadAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, int limit, string continuationToken)
        {
            var items = new List<T>();
            var options = new QueryRequestOptions { MaxItemCount = 1 };
            IQueryable<T> query = _container.GetItemLinqQueryable<T>(true, continuationToken, options).Where(predicate);
            
            using (var iterator = query.ToFeedIterator())
            {
                while (iterator.HasMoreResults && (limit == -1 || entityList.Count < limit))
                {
                    FeedResponse<T> response = await iterator.ReadNextAsync();
                    items.AddRange(response.Resource);
                    continuationToken = response.ContinuationToken;
                }
            }

            return (items, continuationToken);
        }
```

Comment: Not able to understand your question. Can you please elaborate? Please edit your question and provide more details.

Comment: You can set it to any value you want. It doesn't need to be equal to 1.

Comment: I know, but if I want to retrieve say 10 000 records, setting maxItemCount to 10 000 wont drain all the query results, it only returns 7951. Therefore I have to use the While(iterator.hasMoreResults). But setting it to a default number, say 100, wont help either. If you want 101, records, my implementation will give you 200.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding pagination, your approach is correct. What you could do is maintain an internal records counter and adjust it based on the number of documents received.

Here's the pseudo code to do so:

```
public async Task<(IEnumerable<T> Results, string ContinuationToken)> ReadAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, int limit, string continuationToken)
{
    var items = new List<T>();
    int itemsRemaining = limit//Let's say you want to fetch a finite number of items.
    do
    {
        maxItemsCount = Math.Min(itemsRemaining, 100);//assuming you want to fetch a minimum of 100 items at a time
        var options = new QueryRequestOptions { MaxItemCount = maxItemsCount };
        IQueryable<T> query = _container.GetItemLinqQueryable<T>(true, continuationToken, options).Where(predicate);
        
        using (var iterator = query.ToFeedIterator())
        {
            while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
            {
                FeedResponse<T> response = await iterator.ReadNextAsync();
                items.AddRange(response.Resource);
                continuationToken = response.ContinuationToken;
            }
        }
        itemsRemaining -= items.Count;
    }
    while (itemsRemaining > 0);

    return (items, continuationToken);
}
```

In the case where you wish to fetch 101 records, your code will iterate at least twice. First time it will fetch 100 records and the next time it will only fetch 1 record (101 - 100).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this code returns every record in the database because of the while (iterator.HasMoreResults) :(

Comment: Like I said, it's a "pseudo" code. I didn't actually run it. The purpose behind this code is to give you some ideas about how you can accomplish pagination by maintaining an internal counter of items fetched.

Comment: Also, I don't think `iterator.HasMoreResults` will give you problems. Can you share the value of `limit` you're passing in your code? May be I can try running the code this time :).

Comment: It doesn't really matter what the limit is, the iterator still contains every single record in the db that satisfies the predicate, not just the amount spesified by the limit. But try with 10 for instance :)

Comment: I tried `if (iterator.HasMoreResults)` instead of `while`, but what happens is that if MaxItemCount is the same as the remaining records (when you're getting the last ones), it still returns a continuation token that isn't null. The iterator still has one result left with an empty resource.